# Is NMACoreRouter part of Premium Here Maps framework?

Tags: ios, here-api, here-ios

In the NMAKitFramework of the free version (90 day trial) of Here Maps iOS SDK, I am not able to find NMACoreRouter.h file. Is it included only in the premium version?

Answer (score 0):

The free version is the "HERE Starter SDK", and the routing class is there the NMARouteManager (https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-starter/topics/routing-starter.html) while the Premium SDK is using the NMACoreRouter (https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics/routing.html).